# Add Oracle Stemming User-Dictionaries

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, full-text-indexing

I have no concrete example in this [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/text.101/b10730/cdatadic.htm)  to create a custom Stemming User-Dictionaries or add in existing one.

**Example** `Blvd=>Boulevard` stem work OK.

But I need to add `Boul=>Boulevard` in the Dictionary `$ORACLE_HOME/ctx/data/frlx/drfr.dct`.

So as usual, I'm not enough geek to transpose concrete code whit the Oracle documentation.

Thanks for helping me to be oracle lover!